# Generate Option[T] in ScalaCheck

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I am trying to generate optional parameters in ScalaCheck, without success.

There seems to be no direct mechanism for this. `Gen.containerOf[Option, Thing](thingGenerator)` fails because it cannot find an implicit `Buildable[Thing, Option]`.

I tried

```
for {
  thing <- Gen.listOfN[Thing](1, thingGenerator)
} yield thing.headOption
```

But this doesn't work because `listOfN` produces a list that is always of length N. As a result I always get a `Some[Thing]`. Similarly, `listOf1` does not work, because (a) it doesn't produce empty lists, but also (b) it is inefficient because I can't set a max limit on the number of elements.

How can I generate `Option[Thing]` that includes Nones?

**EDIT**: I have found a solution, but it is not succinct. Is there a better way than this?

```
for {
  thing <- for {
    qty <- Gen.choose(0,1)
    things <- Gen.listOfN[Thing](qty, thingGenerator)
  } yield things.headOption
} yield thing
```

**EDIT 2**: I generalised this to

```
def optional[T](g: Gen[T]) = 
  for (qty <- Gen.choose(0, 1); xs <- Gen.listOfN[T](qty, g)) yield xs.headOption
```

So I don't have to write it more than once. But surely this is in the library already and I just missed it?

Comment: About EDIT 2. I just found out that `Gen#option[T]` was introduced with version 1.11.5 of scalacheck - see [here](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/commit/35c8309e7b52eff910dbc6bb1bc727c31ffed07d). The method will return either an instance of `Some[T]` or `None` with equal probability.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Now you can just use:

```
Gen.option(yourGen)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `pick` to randomly choose between a Some and a None generator:

```
val someThing = thingGenerator.map( Some.apply )
val noThing = Gen.value( None:Option[Thing] )
val optThing = Gen.oneOf( someThing, noThing )
```

Comment: See new solution using Gen.option

Comment: @douglaz Nice update. The [actual implementation](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalacheck/Gen.scala#L376) of  `Gen.option` is the one-line version of my answer, so I'll let it for the sake of learning scalacheck. However, your answer is certainly better.